# EF Core Update-Database error "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with smallint"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

EF Core Update-Database failed when i try change column type from datetime to smallint: "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with smallint"

Migration file:

public partial class BookYearFieldChanged : Migration

```
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<short>(
            name: "Published",
            table: "Books",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
            oldType: "date");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "Published",
            table: "Books",
            type: "date",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(short));
    }
}
```

Comment: refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599296/entity-framework-change-key-type

Answer (score 0):

create a new column with required datatype, update the new column with required data and drop the previous column.

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
 [columr1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 [DTime] [datetime] NULL
) 

/* you can't do like this*/
/* alter table table1
 alter column Dtime smallint */
 
ALTER TABLE table1 
ADD DTM smallint

UPDATE table1 
SET DTM = CAST(DTime as smallint)

ALTER TABLE table1 
DROP column DTime

sp_rename 'table1.DTM','DTime','column'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know, that can do with SQL.
But i try to do this with EF commands "Add-Migration" and "Update-Database".
I was interested, may I do smth with scaffolded Migration file,  to do this change right without an error

Answer (score 0):

Basically, EF can't automatically convert the type for you from short to datetime, and it would not make sense to have this conversion anyway. You will have to manually adjust the migration file with something like this.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "Published",
        table: "Books");

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
        name: "Published",
        table: "Books",
        nullable: false,
        type: "datetime2");
}
```

Essentially, this would delete the existing column and replace it with a new one instead of trying to do conversion. You also need to do the same but in reverse for the Down() method.

This would unfortunately result in data loss so make sure to backup your data before updating the db, so you can load it back assuming you need it.